# How to show/embed social media result post with certain hashtag into our website?

Tags: html, facebook, web, embed, social-networking

My objective is: I would like to embed/include some of the posts with the certain hashtag from several social media (Facebook, Instagram, Twitter & LinkedIn) into my website.

For example:

- Hashtag is: #stackoverflow
- Social media: Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Linkedin

I wanna get (e.g.) 10+ posts with the hashtag #stackoverflow from those social media, and include/embed it into my website.

I have tried to achieve by just embedding this page -> https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/stackoverflow with `<iframe>`, but the result is `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/stackoverflow' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

Any clue/idea/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Facebook does not have any API to get posts by hashtag, that is only available for Instagram.